# problem with dataframe / order of columns

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have little problem:
- this is my txt file:

```
month, avg_hig, avg_low, record_high, record_low, avg_precipitation
Jan, 58, 42, 74, 22, 2.85,
Feb, 58, 42, 74, 22, 2.85,
Mar, 58, 42, 74, 22, 2.85,
Apr, 58, 42, 74, 22, 2.85,
May, 58, 42, 74, 22, 2.85,
Jun, 58, 42, 74, 22, 2.85,
Jul, 58, 42, 74, 22, 2.85,
Aug, 58, 42, 74, 22, 2.85,
Sep, 58, 42, 74, 22, 2.85,
Oct, 58, 42, 74, 22, 2.85,
Nov, 58, 42, 74, 22, 2.85,
Dec, 58, 42, 74, 22, 2.85
```

this is my code:

```
header("2. read text file into a df")
filename = 'text.txt'
df = pd.read_csv(filename)
print(df)
```

and then is result:

```
      month   avg_hig   avg_low   record_high   record_low   avg_precipitation
Jan     58        42        74            22         2.85                 NaN
Feb     58        42        74            22         2.85                 NaN
Mar     58        42        74            22         2.85                 NaN
```

Why name of columns is +1 level on right? How to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is last `,` in data - so pandas parse it like new column.

For me working `index_col=False` parameter:

```
df = pd.read_csv(filename, index_col=False)
print (df)
   month   avg_hig   avg_low   record_high   record_low   avg_precipitation
0    Jan        58        42            74           22                2.85
1    Feb        58        42            74           22                2.85
2    Mar        58        42            74           22                2.85
3    Apr        58        42            74           22                2.85
4    May        58        42            74           22                2.85
5    Jun        58        42            74           22                2.85
6    Jul        58        42            74           22                2.85
7    Aug        58        42            74           22                2.85
8    Sep        58        42            74           22                2.85
9    Oct        58        42            74           22                2.85
10   Nov        58        42            74           22                2.85
11   Dec        58        42            74           22                2.85
```